# How to find whether my OS image is corrupted or not?

Tags: windows-xp, iso-image

I'm having Windows XP image as an ISO file. Is there any way to know whether it's corrupted or not?

Comment: use md5checksum

Answer (score 0):

For windows platform you can use Hashcalc. It's a free tool. Once installed

1. Open hashcalc
2. Uncheck all the checkboxes except md5
3. Change data format to file
4. In the data box at the right hand side is a button with 3 dots in click it now navigate to where you downloaded your .iso or .zip and select it and click open

Now press calculate. After a few seconds (or more depending on your computer speed) there will be a string next to the MD5. Now compare that to the md5 hash on the download page. If they are the same then your iso or zip is ok, if not the you need to download it again

The hash should be:

```
Name:: bt4-final.iso
Size: 1570 MB
MD5: af139d2a085978618dc53cabc67b9269

Name:: bt4-final-vm.zip
Size: 2000 MB
MD5: 733b47fad1d56d31bc63c16b3706a11c
```

Download [hashcalc](http://www.slavasoft.com/hashcalc/index.htm)

Comment: pay attention to the [post preview](http://i.imgur.com/E7y2b.png) and learn to use Markdown. All of your posts have been edited and you should learn **not** to depend on others to fix your mistakes

Comment: @sathya i try to correct myself from next post thanks for the edit